# What is a simple dplyr or ifelse command for applying a transformation to two groups of observations in a single data frame column?

Tags: r, if-statement, dplyr

I have ranges of doses for different fungicides. I'm log transforming these doses so that I can do linear regression. For every fungicide, a dose of 0 is used, so I add a constant to the transformations to permit graphing that 0 group. Two different constants are added (either 0.0001 or 0.001), depending on the range of doses used. My ifelse code for transforming my doses works fine, but I know there are better ways within ifelse or within dplyr.

More simply, I'd like a cleaner code which identifies the two target groups and adds their constant to the transformation accordingly.
Could someone suggest a cleaner or simpler code for the sake of learning?
My code:

```
fulldata$log.dose <- ifelse(fulldata$fungicide == "flint24", log(fulldata$dose+0.0001,10),
                      ifelse(fulldata$fungicide == "pristine24.2", log(fulldata$dose+0.0001,10),
                        ifelse(fulldata$fungicide == "flint48", log(fulldata$dose+0.001,10),
                          ifelse(fulldata$fungicide == "pristine24", log(fulldata$dose+0.001,10),
                            ifelse(fulldata$fungicide == "pristine48", log(fulldata$dose+0.001,10),
                              ifelse(fulldata$fungicide == "sylgard24", log(fulldata$dose+0.001,10), NA))))))
fulldata$log.dose <- as.numeric(fulldata$log.dose)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simplify with `case_when` and `%in%`.

```
library(tidyverse)

fulldata %>%
  mutate(
    log.dose = case_when(
      fungicide %in% c("lint24", "pristine24.2") ~ log10(dose + 0.0001),
      fungicide %in% c("lint48", "pristine24", "pristine48", "sylgard24") ~ log10(dose + 0.001)
    )
  )
```

Comment: Awesome, this is what I was looking for. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Here's an approach which separates the creation of the constant from the `log10` operation.

In some cases, it may be useful to refer back to `dose_add` and `log_dose` as distinct columns.

```r
fulldata %>%
  mutate(
    dose_add = if_else(fungicide %in% c("lint24", "pristine24.2"), .0001, .001),
    log_dose = log10(dose + dose_add)
  )
```